# JSTL SQL Tag query

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, jstl

I have couple of jsp which I am refactoring, these jsp use jstl sql tag,

Is their a way to quickly refactor them without touching each of the jsp.

```
<sql:setDataSource  dataSource="jdbc/mydatasource"/>
```

something like injecting the resource annotations in jsp via filter.I need to remove the hardcoded datasource from these jsp, is their way to remove these hardcoding painlessly without going through each of the jsps.

Comment: You can use a tool that can replace text in many files at once, and maybe also regex replace capabilities to make it easier. For example https://www.textpad.com/

Comment: Hmm I was thinking on similar line